# WSO2 API Manager 3.x with Azure AD as Key Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

The requirement is to integrate Azure AD as the Key Manager for WSO2 API Manager 3.x. I have gone through the link to configure a custom key manager but am facing a couple of issues.

1. I am not getting the "Add Key Manager" option in the admin portal
2. What exactly should be the implementation logic for the Azure AD third party key manager? Is there any implementation for Azure AD readily available?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the already supported key managers for APIM 3.2.0 under [Key Managers](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/overview/) in the documentation. To configure a custom key manager, please refer [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-custom-connector/).

Comment: I did see those links. But nothing in there for Azure AD. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to follow the steps under Configure a Custom Key-Manager for this